# What is the ideal VMWare Workstation configuration for local storage and internet connectivity?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vmware-workstation

IS there a general 'high performance' storage and networking configuration for running Linux VMs on VMWare workstation on Windows ?

- I have a very high performance laptop (with SSDs, 6 cores, and 32GB of ram and no other processes of significance running)
- Ive found that mounting shared folders is quite slow - to the point of being unusable for development work.
- Ive also found that the workaround to slow storage, Bridged networks - dont seem to have internet connectivity.
- I am running windows 10 with ubuntu 20.20.

0) Networking

I found a workaround to (1) below, which was to use a BRIDGED network, rather then a NAT network, for VMs in VMWare Workstation, however, when I did this, internet connectivity was gone.

1) Storage performance:

I noticed that storage performance of mounted folders on VMWare workstation can use 100% of my cpu when accessing and cd'ing into large directories...

vmhgfs-fuse on /home/jayunit100/shares type fuse.vmhgfs-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
I clearly can see the file contents as root , and can even cd into these directories.

However as a non root user - i'm not able to change to these mounted directories, and the cd operation hangs. Note that i can ls these files as a non-root user easily...

Why does my ubuntu machine hang when trying to change into a windows mounted filesystem when i do this as non-root?

Is there a way I should be registering users who can / cannot access a folder when i share from Windows folders into Ubuntu?

NOTE: A Workaround I think to this which seems to be ok is running all things as root in the Ubuntu VM. What are the consequences of doing this when accessing files managed by windows?

Comment: What version of VMware?  V15.5.5 is the current newest version.

Answer (score 1):

What version of VMware?  V15.5.5 is the current newest version.

Did you install VMware Tools? (Tools are needed).

I have Ubuntu 18 LTS as a guest on Windows 10 V2004.  I went to the Ubuntu File Manager and connected to the host Windows machine with:

smb://ip_address_of_host/folder_share  (host folder was set to share).  Actual connection time was fine (a bit slower than Windows)

Performance is highly decent, works with NAT or Bridged connections. Internet remains with NAT and Bridged networks.You may need to restart the guest when changing Network types.

Navigating (CD) very large folders on the host does not use much CPU (as expected) .

My Ubuntu User is like a Windows 10 user.  I can use Sudo to do admin chores but did not do this to share files.

Summary:

Make sure you are using VMware V15.5.5
Be very sure Tools are installed. No Tools can impeded sharing.
Share with smb://ipaddress/folder/

As noted, the above is working well for me. Very usable. I also have a fast laptop with large NVMe SSD drive (also fast).

Note: The above steps work just fine in a Kali V2020.2 guest as well.

Comment: What’s wrong with using the shared folders native functionality on workstation? It gives you a /hgfs directory and then suggests you fuse mount it in the docs. Is that wrong ?

Comment: With Tools running, I use SMB mount and that is working fast.  I tried vmhgfs-fuse but it did not want to open the connection.

Comment: I will do some work on this. SMB is folder sharing and works fine. From what I can see FUSE is for mounting folders and the documentation is older https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/60262

Comment: I am not having a lot of success with FUSE. The documentation is a couple of years old. You might consider a newer method